# How do I initialize variables using self.frame in init(size:)

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, initialization, init

My `class` require an `init(size:)` `constructor` for `initialization` and need to call `super.init(size:size)` after my `variables`. This is problematic since I want to initialize my `variables` with `size`. If I try this:

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    tileWidth = self.frame.width/8
    tileHeight = tileWidth/2
    super.init(size: size)
 }
```

...then I get an `error` saying

> 'self' used in property access 'frame' before 'super.init' call

and if I do this:

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    tileWidth = self.frame.width/8 //140
    tileHeight = tileWidth/2
}
```

...I get an error saying

> Property 'self.tileHeight' not initialized at super.init call

So how do I make this happen?

***EDIT***
In its context the code looks like this:

```
class TileBoard: SKScene {

    let tileWidth:CGFloat
    let tileHeight:CGFloat


    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        tileWidth = self.frame.width/8
        tileHeight = tileWidth/2
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }
```

Comment: Make them Optionals? Hard to say if you conceal declarations of class and superclass from us.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
class TopView:UIView {

    var tileWidth:CGFloat?
    var tileHeight:CGFloat?

    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
     }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}



class BottomView:TopView {

     override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        tileWidth = frame.width / 8.0
        tileHeight = tileWidth / 2.0
     }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it using `factory based` `dependency injection` like this:

```
protocol DependencyInjectionProtocol {
    func injection() -> CGFloat
}

class InjectWidth: UIViewController, DependencyInjectionProtocol {
    func injection() -> CGFloat {
        return self.view.frame.width/8.0
    }
}

class InjectHeight: UIViewController, DependencyInjectionProtocol {
    func injection() -> CGFloat {
        let height = (self.view.frame.width/8.0) / 2
        return height
    }
}

class InjectionClient {
    let delegate: DependencyInjectionProtocol

    init(delegate: DependencyInjectionProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}

class TileBoard: SKScene {

    let tileWidth:CGFloat = InjectionClient(delegate: InjectWidth()).delegate.injection()
    let tileHeight:CGFloat = InjectionClient(delegate: InjectHeight()).delegate.injection()

...
```